# How to check if JDialog's has no parent?

Tags: java, swing, parent-child, jdialog

`JDialog` was created with parent that is set to `null`. Like so:

```
final JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
        "A modal Swing JDialog where parent is null.",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
final JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "JDialog where parent is null.");
```

In a class that implements `AWTEventListener` there is `handleOpenedWindow` method:

```
private void handleOpenedWindow(WindowEvent event) {
        final Window window = event.getWindow();
        if (window instanceof Dialog) {

            if (window.getParent() == null
                    || window.getParent().getClass().getName()
                            .contains("SharedOwnerFrame")) {
                updateWindowLocation(window);
            }
        }
    }
```

As alternative I tried to use `window.getOwner().getClass().isAssignableFrom(javax.swing.SwingUtilities.class)` but it is not working.

What is the more elegant way to check if `JDialog` has no parent?

**UPDATE**

`SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(window)` evaluates at runtime as:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame[frame0,0,0,132x38,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:eclipse-rcp]?

Comment: `getOwner()`? `Returns the owner of this window.`